# How to create a colour picture?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, complex

Hope to have a composite colour graphics after I put in complex number, part of t=1 is a color,part of t=2 is another color,and so on.
  Maybe my function is not good.
  How to fix it?
  Thanks a lot!

```
complexTicks[s_] := Transpose[{s, s I}]
ComplexBase4[b_, depth_, t_] := 
  Module[{i = 1}, 
   Show[Graphics[
    Map[
     Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}] &, 
     b^(t) (1 + Nest[Join[b #, b # + b] &, {0}, depth])]
    ], 
    PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    FrameTicks -> {Automatic, complexTicks[Range[-2, 2]], None, None}, 
    PlotStyle -> (ColorData["ColorList"][#3] &)
   ]]
```

I have investigated this function in the past:

```
ComplexBase1[b_, depth_] := 
Module[{i = 1}, 
 Show[Graphics[
   Map[Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}] &, Nest[Join[b #, b # + b] &, {0}, depth]
 ]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, complexTicks[Range[-2, 2]], None, None}]
]
```

Then, I test some complex numbers like  `ComplexBase1[0.4 + 0.6 I, 15]`

Comment: "Maybe my function is not good.  How to fix it?"  What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Options for Graphics[], there is not option PlotStyle. All color functions must be put forward Point[]. Try this model

```
complexTicks[s_] := Transpose[{s, s I}]
ComplexBase4[b_, depth_, t_] := 
 Module[{i = 1}, 
  Show[Graphics[
    Map[{Hue[Abs[#], 1, 1, .3], Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}]} &, 
     b^(t) (1 + Nest[Join[b #, b # + b] &, {0}, depth])]], 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, complexTicks[Range[-2, 2]], None, None}]]
ComplexBase4[0.4 + 0.6 I, 15, 3]
```

[image: fig1]